# Group numbers by numerical order in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to group numbers that are in numerical order from an array.

(using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.2)

```
Example1:
[1,2,4,5,6]

Example2:
[1,3,4,6,7]

Example3:
[1,2,3,5,6]

Example4:
[1,2,4,5,7]
```

After grouping

```
Example1:
[[1,2],[4,5,6]]

Example2:
[[1],[3,4],[6,7]]

Example3:
[[1,2,3],[5,6]]

Example4:
[[1,2],[4,5],[7]]
```

You get the idea.
(What I'm actually doing is grouping days, not relevant though)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to group the *consecutive* numbers together, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you'd call this operation, but it's a sort of grouping method based on the last element processed. Something like:

```
def groupulate(list)
  list.inject([ ]) do |result, n|
    if (result[-1] and result[-1][-1] == n - 1)
      result[-1] << n
    else
      result << [ n ]
    end

    result
  end
end
```

The Enumerable module provides a large number of utility methods for processing lists, but `inject` is the most flexible by far.

Comment: Perfect, marking this as correct answer, even though @tjdett's answer is the same. Thank you.

Comment: [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) probably makes more sense here than `inject`, since you're just passing the same object between iterations.

Comment: In 1.9, yeah, `each_with_object` is probably a better call.

Comment: Any reason for preferring `[-1]` over `.last`?

Comment: Since `[-1]` is equivalent to `.last`, it's somewhat a matter of preference. I try to avoid making chains like `array[2].last[3]` since it looks more confusing than `array[2][-1][3]` but that's up to you. In this case you don't have that conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect problem to use `inject` (aka `reduce`) with:

```
def group_consecutive(arr)
  arr.inject([[]]) do |memo, num|
    if memo.last.count == 0 or memo.last.last == num - 1
      memo.last << num
    else
      memo << [ num ]
    end
    memo
  end
end
```

See it run here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/0d0a5

Comment: As noted on the other answer using `inject` as well, [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) probably makes more sense here than `inject`, since you're just passing the same object between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,4,5,7]
out = []
a.each_index do |i|
  if out.last and out.last.last == a[i]-1
    out.last << a[i]
  else
    out << [a[i]]
  end
end

puts out.inspect
```

Comment: Yes, you always get amazed by the solution of problems like this in ruby :)

Comment: Well, my solutions is more C than Ruby, but absolutely, you can do so many pretty things in Ruby.